# Counting Sort - C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, counting-sort

So I tried to implement Counting Sort as an exercise, but there is a mistake that I'm not able to fix.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void ordenar(int vet[], int b, int k)
{
    int num[k];
    int c0=0,c1=0, n, frescura=0;

    for (n=0; n<k+1; n++)
    {
        num[n] = 0;
    }

    for(n=0;n<b+1;n++)
    {
        num[vet[n]]++;
    }

    for(n=0;n<=b;)
        {
        while(num[frescura]>0)
        {
            vet[n] = frescura;
            n++;
            num[frescura]--;
        }
        frescura++;
        }
    int y;
    for (y=0; y<b+1; y++)
    {
        printf("%d, ", vet[y]);
    }

}

main ()
{
    int a[]={8,2,3,4,1,45,12,23,1,4,5,1,9,2,4,82,0,3,0,0,0,0,23,4,8,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,2,4,
            1,3,3,3,3,4,21,4,2,4,1,4,12,4,1,4,2,4,2,95,32,32,23,41,14,0,0,1,4,24,24,2,
            2,2,2,2,2,1,3,14,14,15,5,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,666,4,3,2,1,9,3,4,2,1,0,51,23,12,
            23,23,14,15,16,18,81,28,18,19,20,3,1,9,9,9,2,4,1,65,2,13,13,29,93,42,6}, b, k=666;

    b = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    ordenar(a, b, 666);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is: the code seems to put this array in order, except for the penultimate number, which is the number of elements of said array.

Comment: What is it with the strange upper bounds? `num[n]` accesses `num` out of bounds when `n == k`, which your `for` loop will reach.

Comment: `int a[]={8,2,3,...,93,42,6}, b, k=666;` is really **terrible** style; I was looking like a madman for where `b` was defined and then I had to think about what type something gets that is defined as `int a[]=..., b`.

Comment: `for (n=0; n<k+1; n++)` should be `for (n=0; n<k; n++) `

And one other thing.. What do you mean by "penultimate number"? Number of elements in an array is not element of array itself!

Comment: If I swap
for (n=0; n<k+1; n++)
with
for (n=0; n<k; n++) 
the code crashes. Also, by "penultimate number", I mean the ordered array has the number "128" right before the "666". "128" is not on the original array and is the number of elements of a[].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined `num` as

```
int num[k];
```

and later are accessing elements till `k`

```
for (n=0; n<k+1; n++) // 0 to k
{
    num[n] = 0;
}
```

But, as the index of arrays starts from `0` , the array would have elements indexed from `0` to `k-1`

So, the above code would result in accessing elements out of bound. Which is Undefined Behavior in C

Answer (score 0):

```
int num[k];                  //has valid index from 0 to k-1

for (n=0; n<k+1; n++)        // this will access index k(out of bounds)
{
    num[n] = 0;             
}
```

With `n=k` it goes out of bound , thus you tend to write at invalid address therefore ,causing UB.

Change loop condition to `n<k` .

```
for (n=0; n<k; n++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about the dimensions of your arrays:

- `b` is the number of elements in `a`. You can access `a[0]` through a`[b - 1]` incusively; `a[b]` is one beyond the array.
- `k` is the maximum value of the elements in `a`. You must be able to store all elements from 0 to `k` inclusively in `num`. That's `k + 1` elements, and that should also be your dimension for `num`:

So your first `for` loop is good, but the array dimension is one too small. Your second and third loops iterate over `a` and should therefore have the condition `n < b`. Both loops do one iteration too many in your code.

```
void ordenar(int vet[], int b, int k)
{
    int num[k + 1];
    int n, frescura = 0;

    for (n = 0; n < k + 1; n++) {           // initialise num
        num[n] = 0;
    }

    for (n = 0; n < b; n++) {               // accumulate counts
        num[vet[n]]++;
    }

    for (n = 0; n < b;) {                   // reconstruct array
        while (num[frescura] > 0) {
            vet[n] = frescura;
            n++;
            num[frescura]--;
        }
        frescura++;
    }
}
```

Further notes:

- The last `for` loop is awkward. The idea is to loop over all possible elements in increasing order and then fill the original array with the respective number of elements. So the outer loop should iterate over `num` and the inner loop should fill the array:

  ```
  m = 0;
  for (n = 0; n < k + 1; n++) {
      while (num[n]-- > 0) vet[m++] = n;
  }
  ```

  (Your version isn't wrong, but it is harder to understand, in my opinion. I've replaced the long name `frescura` with `m`)
- You should probably enforce that all array elements are between 0 and `k`. The value is used as index into `num` and accessing that array at indices out of bound leads to undefined behaviour.
- Printing shouldn't be part of the sorting function; it should be done in a separate function.